# How to render custom UINavigationBar in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode

In Interface Builder, I have set my navigation bar to a custom UINavigationBar, but it does not render with my drawRect override.  I'm using a storyboard with XCode 4.5.1.

Comment: Do you want IB to run your drawRect: method and render it? I don't think it will.

Comment: Yes.  It has background images I would like to see in IB.